# Why maxRequestLength set is invalid in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, maxrequestlength

In the web.config, I've set maxRequestLength to 102400. When I upload a 65M file, it redirects me to a 404 error page, but it is normal in asp.net. This is the current setting:

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="102400"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to upload a small file, its work? I think this kind of error isn't related with maxRequestLength. Verify your Upload Action, or write here for us.

Comment: arnistrong,Thanks for your answer,i upload a small file,it's no problem,if it is bigger than 50M appear an error page.

Comment: This is a asp.net web page,I run it in asp.net web application is OK,I array it in MVC project,then link to this page appear this problem.

Comment: You need to include relevant code in your initial question so we can help you. Like arnistrong said, it's not likely to be a problem with the setting, but in your code; e.g your upload action.